# GetHashCode issue

Tags: c#, .net, equals, hashcode

Can anyone help explain the following. I am having an issue with a Dictionary where `ContainsKey` evaluates to false while both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for the objects are successful. Below is the output from the immediate window in Visual Studio:

```
?LocationToRackingGroup.Keys.ToArray()[23].Equals(location)
true
?LocationToRackingGroup.Keys.ToArray()[23] == (location)
true
?this.LocationToRackingGroup.ContainsKey(location)
false
```

Am I missing something? Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is location mutable?
Because if it is, it might have changed since you put it into the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'd want to look at a couple of things:

1: is `GetHashCode` correctly implemented:

```
?LocationToRackingGroup.Keys.ToArray()[23].GetHashCode() == location.GetHashCode()
```

2: if this is the generic dictionary, does the type also implement (explicitly) `IEquatable<Location>`

3: did you supply a custom `IEqualityComparer<Location>` to the dictionary in the constructor?

To rule out the last, perhaps look at:

```
?LocationToRackingGroup.Comparer.Equals(blah23, location); // should be true
?LocationToRackingGroup.Comparer.GetHashCode(blah23);  // should equal below
?LocationToRackingGroup.Comparer.GetHashCode(location);// should equal above
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response:

1. GetHashCode is equal for both, I meant to include that sorry:

?LocationToRackingGroup.Keys.ToArray()[23].GetHashCode()
973699796
location.GetHashCode()
973699796

2. I hadn't implemented IEquatable explicitly but have just tried that and it made no difference I am afraid.

3. I don't think this should make a difference. If I am correct it should use the default IEqualityComparer Equals which has been overriden.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at Robert's answer? Other than that, we'd probably need something reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is a long shot.

In the first two lines you refer to `LocationToRackingGroup` and in the last to `this.LocationToRackingGroup`, are they the same variable?

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that the hashcode must be the same for every 'instance' of the same data. If it changes, then your hash function is broken.

IOW, the safest hash function is:

```
int GetHashcode()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This defeats the usefulness of the hash code method, but is technically a legal implementation; might be helpful to try this for debugging